# gestion des formulaires et des membres inscrits

Tags: joomla-4.x

On behalf of an association, I make a new site that involves forms.
I use Joomla 4 and Nicepage essentially. The site is in 2 parts: public and private. The private part requires registration which will in principle allow access to the private part. The private part is a training area where each page will lead to the next after a series of questions which, depending on the result, will open the next section or not. For each new section reached, the identifier and the MDP will be necessary.
Being quite a beginner on Joomla, I have a lot of trouble, because I do not master Joomla at all and even less the forms. I find it hard to find myself there between entry, recovery of information, then install the forms by session zone. I have been trying solutions for more than a week, following tutorials, and there I take the lead so much that everything mixes. This is surely a stupid thing that I did not capture, so I think it is time that a good soul comes to guide me ... please, thank you, Eric

Comment: Eric, one of the rules of Stack Exchange apparently is that questions must be asked in English so I am not allowed to translate your question(but you can) and respond. If you are unable to re-post your question in English, assuming you can read this comment, you could try asking on a french board at https://forum.joomla.org/viewforum.php?f=19&sid=21c8e219bd9418c102a1a4283ef82dbc j  or seek out a local user group, https://community.joomla.org/user-groups.html